# Understanding method returning BOOL by using !=

Tags: objective-c, ios, return-value, boolean

This is a rather basic question regarding the syntax of the return statement in the `shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method of a view controller.

In order to allow all views except for the upside-down portrait mode, I have the following chunk of code implemented:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

What exactly is the return statement doing? I understand that it is returning a boolean variable, but how is it determining whether to return true or false? Is this a kind of implicit if statement inside of the return statement? I.e. would:

```
-    (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    if (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
        return YES;
}
```

technically be the same thing, just more explicitly stated?

Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The result of a comparison like `(something != something_else)` is a `BOOL` value. If the comparison is true, the expression `(....)` takes the value `YES` (which is the same as `TRUE`).

It isn't an implicit conversion, it is just how comparisons work.

Comment: Oh wow that makes sense, I've just never seen that syntax before so it had my head spinning. Thanks!